# $\frac{1}{1+z}$ Laurent series

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

**Exercise**: find the Laurent series of $\frac{1}{1+z}$ where $|z|>1$

**my solution:**  $\frac{1}{1+z}= \frac{1}{z(1+\frac{1}{z})}$, since $|z|>1 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{|z|}<1$

$$\frac{1}{z(1+\frac{1}{z})}= \frac{1}{z}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty }\left (\frac{-1}{z}  \right )^n=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty } \frac{(-1)^n}{z^{n+1}}  $$

**Is it correct ?**

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right; when you have this kind of problems the tip is trying to factorize in an estrategic way to have a geometric sequence.